# Where to get ubuntu-4.4.0-78.iso?

Tags: boot, server, system-installation

Somehow my /boot got completely erased.  The oldest version I see to download is 14.04.6 LTS (Trusty Tahr).

Comment: Kernel 4.4 = Ubuntu 16.04. Community support for Ubuntu 16.04 ended in 2021. We no longer provide those install iso images, and we no longer answer questions about that release. Consider backing up your data and then migrating to a newer, supported release of Ubuntu.

Comment: The earliest Ubuntu iso can still be found at http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/

Comment: Note kernel 4.4.0-243 is the latest version available via esm.  If you don't upgrade to a later release, at least get the current 4.4 available.

Comment: Thanks rocky rocky, but don't I need to download Trusty?  It isn't at https://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/

Comment: ubfan1 -- issue is I have a ZFS pool that apparently does not like newer versions of Ubuntu.  I would love to get current w/ Ubuntu, but either the ZFS pool or my motherboard's BIOS do not like newer versions.

Comment: Ubunru 14.04 can be upgraded to kernel 4.4, but Ubuntu 16.04 initially came with the 4.4 kernel.  Keep what you have and just get the latest 4.4 kernel. then join ems and upgrade to the latest 4.4 kernel. Look at other places, like cdimage for old releases. Not sure which one has what you need.

Comment: All Ubuntu releases can be found here http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/